# Does a trailing slash matter in HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, http, get

I'm writing an app that makes calls to Tesla's API and am trying to capture the base URL in a variable. The URL's all have a similar base:

```
https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles
```

All but one of the endpoints add further paths onto that URL, and it always starts by adding the vehicle ID. My question is, if I make a variable that has this as the base path:

```
https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/api/1/vehicles/
```

Would making a GET request to that URL function the same as making a GET request to the version without the trailing slash? This would help clean the code up a bit if so. I'm writing in Javascript if that matters.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it depends on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `..vehicles` is not the same URI as `..vehicles/`. Quite obviously they're different. **Whether this matters for this particular URI depends on the URI/web server.**

A web server is free to respond to any URI request in any manner possible. The server may or may not normalise the URI, it may or may not treat URIs with and without trailing slash identically, it may or may not treat it the same for some URIs but not for others. The only thing you can do is try with your particular URI on your particular web server.

Comment: Shoot, OK. I'll accept this answer in 7 minutes, since we're on a tight schedule with this, I guess I'm going to have to just make my URL's a little less pretty looking now, oh well.